Catch ALL unhandled exceptions in Blazor MAUI Hybrid
Our problem is our production app is crashing and we don't know why. I need to be able to catch these errors in order to send crash analytics but the exceptions in question are sneaking through all error catching logic.
I have error catching logic using an ErrorBoundary component wrapping the entire application. This catches most exceptions however some exceptions still sneak through not triggering any error handling logic and showing the default error: 
Digging around I've found one exception is being thrown from a components DisposeAsync method. To reproduce, create a component that implements IAsyncDisposable like so:
@implements IAsyncDisposable

@code {
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("How can I catch this?");
    }
}

I have tried the solutions in Show details of uncaught exception in Blazor UI and Is there a way to globally catch all unhandled errors in a Blazor single page application? including both the ErrorBoundary and ILogger approaches but neither catches this error. Those questions are also for Blazor WASM not Blazor Hybrid so there could be some differences.

Blazor Maui doesn't use webassembly - is that a mistake in your question or have you built a custom Maui hybrid app that uses webassembly?

Thanks @MisterMagoo this is a mistake in my question I'll edit it

You can catch the error and at least be able to log it by adding a FirstChanceException handler to the application. This won't give you any method for preventing the unhandled error in the BlazorWebView - but it may help find the cause of the crashes.
You can do something like this, but actually log the exception using whatever logging you prefer.
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s, e) =>
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("********** OMG! FirstChanceException **********");
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Exception);
};

Where you add this is up to you - it could be in MauiProgram.cs or App.xaml.cs for instance.

this was really helpful!
